# Using static href with query string in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, apache, thymeleaf

I have a html prototype of an application, this prototype is on an Apache server, I used Apache Server Side Includes to include different pages for the template layouts.

Now I'm adding labels Thymeleaf that prototype for use in an application with Spring.
The problem is that many of the URLs that are used need Query String to load content with Apache and that generates an error using Thymeleaf.

For example, a link in the static prototype looks like this:

```
<a href="index.html?seccion=asignaturas&area=materiales-editar"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Registrar material</a>
```

Adding Thymeleaf should look like:

```
<a href="index.html?seccion=asignaturas&area=materiales-editar" th:href="@{/asignaturas/{idAsignatura}/seccion/{idSeccion}/materiales/registro.html(idAsignatura=${asignatura.id},idSeccion=${asignatura.idSeccion},idfuncion=${param.idfuncion},idmodulo=${param.idmodulo})}"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Registrar material</a>
```

But the application crashes, error checking static Query String url (**?seccion=asignaturas**)

Could you live my prototype (running on Apache, to get SSI) with thymeleaf labels on my actual application?

Comment: Post your thymeleaf  template  so we can see what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not escaping the "&" as recommended herein ([Escaping the & character](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/189#issuecomment-20864112)).
My link was as follows:

```
<a href="index.html?seccion=asignaturas&amp;area=materiales-editar" th:href="@{/asignaturas/{idAsignatura}/seccion/{idSeccion}/materiales/registro.html(idAsignatura=${asignatura.id},idSeccion=${asignatura.idSeccion},idfuncion=${param.idfuncion},idmodulo=${param.idmodulo})}"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Registrar material</a>
```

Now I do not have any error. Thanks!